# Buffered channel appears to store more values than my buffer size

Tags: go

I'm currently learning about channels and have written this code expecting it to fail but it didn't. What is actually happening under the hood here? From my understanding if the buffer size is 2, then I should only be able to store 2 values at a time without getting deadlocked. Am I missing a fundamental understanding off the bat?

```
c := make(chan int, 2)

go func() {
    c <- 1
    c <- 2
    c <- 3
    c <- 4
    c <- 5
    c <- 6
}()

fmt.Println(<-c)
...
fmt.Println(<-c)
```

So after thinking maybe the channel is getting filled with 2 values and concurrently executing each Println(<-c) once the memory is unlocked for whatever reason. I wrote the next snippet trying to stop that from happening and cause the deadlock error and it ran as well.

```
c := make(chan int, 2)

go func() {
    c <- 1
    c <- 2
    c <- 3
    c <- 4
    c <- 5
    c <- 6
}()

fmt.Println(<-c, <-c, <-c, <-c, <-c, <-c)
```

Why does this buffered channel appear to allow me to store more than 2 values in it, and if my fundamental understanding of channels is incorrect, could someone lead my to a good source to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

It is storing only two values. The goroutine starts running, and writes to the channel one by one. But at the same time, the main goroutine is also running, and reading from the channel. You read just enough to consume all the values in the channel, so no deadlock.

Comment: I see thanks for clarifying, It doesn't work if I try to read more than provided. But why does a buffer size exist if it's able to handle itself correctly this way?

Comment: A non-zero channel capacity allows the writer to write in finite bursts, especially if the reader cannot keep up with such bursts.